# Is there a way to capture panaroma image in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, camera

i want to capture a vertical panorama image with the camera. I was looking around and couldnt find anything. Any kind of help is appreciated :)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Yalzeee sorry, no.